# Enable usage of TLS 1.2 in soapUI Pro

Tags: java, ssl

I need to connect to a webservice which only accepts connections established via TLS 1.2. Other versions are not supported.

My test client (soapUI Pro) uses JRE 1.7_45 which - according to the following link - generally supports TLS 1.2 which is not enabled by default for clients. I don't have control over the test client's source code so I need to enable TLS 1.2 via some Java options or else.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#tlsprotonote

However I cannot find any information how to enable TLS 1.2 for the JVM.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following parameter must be added to the soapUI vmoptions file in soapUI's bin directory:

```
-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

Comment: I also needed to add: -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true to the JAVA_OPTS to make this work.

Answer (score 8):

You need to pass the protocol to `SSLContext` - [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String%29)

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
```

You can then use `context` to create an `SSLEngine`

```
context.createSSLEngine();
```

Read the [JSSE guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLENG) on how to make SSL connections using `SSLEngine`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I don't have control over the test client's source code. I have reworked my question so that I need some -D switch or else.